# Can't figure out how to have text content shown based on the date automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

I am looking to have text shown in a paragraph that changes based on the date. This is for a hotel website where the price is based on the seasons and I find it horribly tacky to list out every season's rate in the main price section. Here is my current code that I am having trouble fiddling with to get it to do what I want:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {
    var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.DateRange,
.DateDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">3/1/2016 to 5/14/2016</span>$89</div>
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">5/15/2016 to 9/14/2016</span>$129</div>
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">9/15/2016 to 12/1/2016</span>$89</div>
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">12/1/2016 to 2/28/2017</span>$49</div>
```

This works on a basic end of what I want, in that it shows the price of what I need during that rate period though I will have to manually change the code on a yearly basis... if someone knows how to set it up so I don't have to do that, that would be great.

Comment: I don't follow. It works, so what do you need help with?

Comment: How would I set it up to change the year automatically? Like, if the prices per season don't change year from year.

Comment: Is it only the years that change? The months and days do not change?

Comment: Correct. Right now, the seasons do not change year from year, always the same dates regardless of what year it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first set the dates of the `DateRange` elements prior to calculating the effective rate. What I have done is used a string of characters `####` to represent this year and `XXXX` to represent next year. Then use a global string replace method in Javascript prior to setting them inside the `DateRange` elements.

```
$(function() {
  var dates = ['3/1/#### to 5/14/####','5/15/#### to 9/14/####', '9/15/#### to 12/1/####','12/1/#### to 2/28/XXXX'];
  var d = new Date();
  var thisYear = d.getFullYear();
  var nextYear = d.getFullYear() + 1;

  $('.DateRange').each(function(index){
    var datesInd = dates[index];
    datesInd = datesInd.replace(/####/g,thisYear);
    datesInd = datesInd.replace(/XXXX/g,nextYear);
    $(this).eq(index).text(datesInd);
  });

  $(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {
    var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

**Shortened Method**

I put the prior code in this post to make it easier for you to visualize it. You should minimize the code into one loop.

```
$(function() {
  var dates = ['3/1/#### to 5/14/####','5/15/#### to 9/14/####', '9/15/#### to 12/1/####','12/1/#### to 2/28/XXXX'];
  var d = new Date();
  var thisYear = d.getFullYear();
  var nextYear = d.getFullYear() + 1;

  $(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {  
    var datesInd = dates[index];
    datesInd = datesInd.replace(/####/g,thisYear);
    datesInd = datesInd.replace(/XXXX/g,nextYear);
    $('DateRange').eq(index).text(datesInd);

    var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/te75gwm4/1/

Based on your comment, you also need this dollar amount in other portions of your web page. Just get the dollar amount value and send it to another function that updates a specific `.dollar-amount` class. Add this `dollar-amount` class wherever you need this dollar amount.

```
$(function() {
  var dates = ['3/1/#### to 5/14/####','5/15/#### to 9/14/####', '9/15/#### to 12/1/####','12/1/#### to 2/28/XXXX'];
  var d = new Date();
  var thisYear = d.getFullYear();
  var nextYear = d.getFullYear() + 1;

  $(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {  
    var datesInd = dates[index];
    datesInd = datesInd.replace(/####/g,thisYear);
    datesInd = datesInd.replace(/XXXX/g,nextYear);
    $('DateRange').eq(index).text(datesInd);

    var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo){
      $(this).show();
      var requiredText = $(this).text();
      requiredText = '$' + requiredText.split('$')[1];
      inputEverywhere(requiredText);
    }
  });

  function inputEverywhere(dollarAmount){
    $('.dollar-amount').each(function(index){
        $(this).text(dollarAmount);
    });
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/te75gwm4/2/

**Note where I have manipulated the text using the `split` function.**

Comment: Hot damn! Thank you sooo much! This works exactly how I wanted it too!

Comment: This works great... except that it only shows the output once per page. I have, roughly, a dozen instances on the page where I need to show the output. Mine works, but I need to manually change it yearly.

Comment: Damn, that was quick! Thank you!

What about if I need the dollar amount to be different in each placement? If I have, lets say, 5 different rooms who each has a different rate based on the unchanging season dates?

Comment: You would need to apply the same type of logic to those elements. Just look at what I did and attempt to recreate it. Then see if there is an easier way to recreate them all at once. If you are having trouble, I recommend asking another question and referencing this question to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am late with the answer, but because I wrote something I will post it also.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  function displayPrice() {
    var r = [
      {left: {m: 3, d: 1}, right: {m: 5, d: 14}, price: 89},
      {left: {m: 5, d: 15}, right: {m: 9, d: 14}, price: 129},
      {left: {m: 9, d: 15}, right: {m: 12, d: 1}, price: 89},
      {left: {m: 12, d: 1}, right: {m: 2, d: 28}, price: 49}
    ];
    var dtNow = new Date(),
        dtY = dtNow.getFullYear(),
        dtM = dtNow.getMonth() + 1,
        dtFrom,
        dtTo,
        $elem = $('.DateDiv'),
        lY = dtY,
        rY = dtY;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
      lY = dtY;
      rY = dtY;
      if (r[i].left.m > r[i].right.m) {
          if (dtM < r[i].left.m) {
            lY--;
          } else {
            rY++;
          }
        }
      dtFrom = new Date(lY, r[i].left.m - 1, r[i].left.d);
      dtTo = new Date(rY, r[i].right.m - 1, r[i].right.d);
      if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo) {
        $elem.html('<span class="DateRange">'
                   + r[i].left.m + '/' + r[i].left.d + '/' + lY
                   + ' to '
                   + r[i].right.m + '/' + r[i].right.d + '/' + rY
                   + '</span> $' + r[i].price);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  displayPrice();
  
});
```

```html
<div class="DateDiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```